# Unbearable rattling from one of my YORK furnaces

Tags: furnace, noise

i have a pair of YORK furnaces installed in my basement. Once a while one of them starts making unbearable rattling noise - maybe once every couple weeks, and the noise lasted, i don't know, hours?

I looked for the source of noise and found it's from this little guy - see below

[image]

**Model: VCMA-15ULS**

[image]

**Little Giant Pump Company, Oklahoma City, OK**

My apology that I couldn't provide more info as I don't know too much about furnace. Could it be the weather being hot so that the furnace is overloaded?
However any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Can you get us a model number, and a closeup shot of the thing?

Comment: sure, thank you! Post updated. The image might still be unclear so i wrote down the model# and manufacturer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like an condensate pump. They're used to pump the waste condensate water to a drain that's higher than or far away from the furnace's outlet. It collects water in the tank until a float triggers the pump to eject it.

It's not a part of the furnace itself. I'm not sure if it's serviceable but a replacement should be available at local home center for around $50.

Comment: Thank you! I'll do an experiment to determine if the pump indeed malfunctioned.